# Material-Table : TypeError: Object(...) is not a function Module../node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/dist/material-ui-pickers.esm.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to install material-table for my React application but when i'm trying the example code (https://github.com/mbrn/material-table) but I get an error message from a file of the module.

I tried to update material-ui it's on the 5.8.0 version.

code from the doc :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
        <MaterialTable
          columns={[
            { title: "Adı", field: "name" },
            { title: "Soyadı", field: "surname" },
            { title: "Doğum Yılı", field: "birthYear", type: "numeric" },
            {
              title: "Doğum Yeri",
              field: "birthCity",
              lookup: { 34: "İstanbul", 63: "Şanlıurfa" }
            }
          ]}
          data={[
            { name: "Mehmet", surname: "Baran", birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 }
          ]}
          title="Demo Title"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react-div"));
```

Error message :

```py
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
Module../node_modules/@material-ui/pickers/dist/material-ui-pickers.esm.js
```

```
39859 |   return utils;
39860 | }
39861 | 
> 39862 | var useStyles =Object(_material_ui_core_styles__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__["makeStyles"])(function (theme) {                                                                                39863 |   var textColor = theme.palette.type === 'light' ? theme.palette.primary.contrastText : theme.palette.getContrastText(theme.palette.background.default);
39864 |   return {                                                           
39865 |     toolbarTxt: {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen because your version of `material-table` is incompatible with version of `material-ui`. For example take a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-material-table-versioning-issue-oeqij

`@material-ui/core` version is 3.9.3
`material-table` version is 1.39.2

The same error happens: `makeStyles is not a function`

But if you bump the version of `@material-ui/core` to version `4.1.2.` (latest at the moment) the error goes away. At least this is what helped me. I also had to update `material-ui-pickers` to `@material-ui/pickers` (new name, latest version to avoid having old material-ui as a dependency)

Comment: So what I should do is : 


npm install @material-ui/core4.1.2
then
npm install @material-ui/pickers

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
const MaterialTable = require("material-table");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.